# UUIDを指定せずにiBeaconの電波を受信することは可能でしょうか

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon

UUID問わず、近くにあるiBeaconの一覧を出したいと考えています。
UUIDを指定せずにiBeaconの電波を受信することは可能でしょうか。

どうぞよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

以前、REBL600FRをiBeacon発信器とした場合の検知アプリを開発しました。
CoreBluetooth.frameworkを使って、アドバタイズパケットをスキャンしていました。
major, minorの値も検知できました。

参考：REBL600FRを検知するiOSアプリを開発してみた！
http://grandbig.github.io/blog/2015/02/08/bl600sample2/

参考：REBL600FRの発信パラメータをiOSアプリで変更してみた！
http://grandbig.github.io/blog/2015/02/11/bl600sample3/

同様の方法でできるかわかりませんが試してみてはいかがでしょうか。
（ただし、Aplixから販売されているMyBeaconはセキュリティのせいか検出できませんでした。）

Answer (score 1):

ビーコンはBluetoothデバイスですので、`CoreBluetooth`のAPIを利用すればスキャン可能です。

…ですが[見つかったデバイスからビーコンとしての情報を得ることは出来ない](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/10/21/corebluetooth-doesnt-let-you-see-ibeacons.html)模様です。

Answer (score 1):

"BLExplr"というアプリが存在しているため、技術的には可能です。

Answer (score 1):

CoreBluetooth ではビーコンを受信できません。
Apple としてはビーコンを位置情報として扱っているので、CoreBluetooth でビーコンを受信できたら、位置情報のユーザー確認無しに位置情報を取得できることになります。

CoreLocation で、UUID を指定しない方法が無い以上無理です。